# Why SSH key login asking me the Passphrase every time?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I use PuTTY and followed this tutorial:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

Every time I login I"m being asked to input the passphrase. How do I avoid having to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `pageant` and add keys to it once after system startup or just leave passwords empty.

Answer (score -2):

On page 2 of that tutorial (part 5) when generating the key you enter a passphrase which is needed to access that key. Leave the password blank.

If putty doesn't allow you to create a key without a password then you could create the key with ssh-keygen on the remote *nix machine and copy it back to your machine.